# MongoDB addFields based on condition (array of array)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have a sample object as below

```
[
  {
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "person": [
      {
        "name": "Jim",
        "age": "2",
        "qualification": [
          {
            "type": "education",
            "degree": {
              "name": "bachelor",
              "year": "2022"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "certification",
            "degree": {
              "name": "aws",
              "year": "2021"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now, I need to add a field "score" only when the qualification.type == bachelor

This is the query I tried but could not get the proper result. Not sure what mistake I am doing. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "person.qualification.score": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$person.qualification",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$this.type",
                  "bachelor"
                ]
              },
              "80",
              "$$REMOVE"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Based on attached document, no subdocument matches `qualification.type == bachelor` condition.

Comment: This problem is similar to an example in the MongoDB documentation for the `$[]` operator, to [Update Nested Arrays](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with----identifier--). It may be worth taking a look. You may also clarify the concern @YongShun pointed out.

Comment: sorry @YongShun the condition should be a qualification.type == education

Comment: What is the desired outcome? All qualification documents with a `type` of `education` have a `score` set to `80`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$set` - Set `person` array field.

   1.1. `$map` - Iterate `person` array and return a new array.

   1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge current iterate (`person`) document and the document with `qualification`.

   1.1.1.1. `$map` - Iterate the `qualification` array and return a new array.

   1.1.1.1.1. `$cond` - Match `type` of current iterate `qualification` document. If true, merge current iterate `qualification` document and the document with `score` field via `$mergeObjects`. Else remain the existing document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      person: {
        $map: {
          input: "$person",
          as: "p",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$p",
              {
                qualification: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$p.qualification",
                    in: {
                      $cond: {
                        if: {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$this.type",
                            "education"
                          ]
                        },
                        then: {
                          $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$this",
                            {
                              score: "80"
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        else: "$$this"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/02NzAViwVFH)